# Move semantics with non-pointer data members

Tags: c++, pointers, move-semantics

Probably this has been asked and answered already, but I don't know what to search for.

Can move semantics be used for non-pointer data members, if the data members have move assignment operators defined?

Suppose I have a class `M` that defines `M::operator=(M&&)` like this:

```
template <class T>
class M
{
public: 
    M()
    {
        mem_M = new T;
    }

    M& operator=(M&& src)
    {
        if (this != &src)
        {
            mem_M = src.mem_M;
            src.mem_M = nullptr;
        }
        return *this;
    }

private:    
    T* mem_M;
};
```

Now obviously I can have a class `C<T>` like this, with a move constructor that makes no use of `T`'s move assignment operator:

```
template <class T>
class C
{
public:
    C ()
    {
        mem_C = new T;
    }
    C (C&& rhs)
    {
        mem_C = rhs.mem_C;
        rhs.mem_C = nullptr;
    }

private:
    T* mem_C;
};
```

However, what if I wanted `C<T>::mem_C` to not be a pointer but an ordinary member, how would I deal with `C<T>::mem_C` in the move-functions? I can of course invoke the move assignment operator `T::operator=(T&&)` to move the filed `mem_C` from one instance to the other, but how do I properly reset the instance of `C` passed to `C<T>::C(C&&)`?

This at least looks wrong to me:

```
template <class T>
class C
{
public:
    C ()
    {
        mem_C = T();
    }
    C (C<T>&& rhs)
    {
        mem_C = std::move(rhs.mem_C);
        rhs.mem_C = T();          // ?? like this?
    }

private:
    T mem_C;
};
```

So, what is the standard compliant way to reset non-pointer data members in move functions?

Comment: Pointers are a subset of "ordinary member". You seem to be asking about the difference between moving class types and non-class types

Comment: `mem_C = T();` should be removed, the object is already constructed so this just wastes time and resources.

Comment: In this case, you can and should use the defaulted move-assignment operator (see [Rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three))

Comment: @M.M but if `mem_C` was a vector of a million elements? Would freeing up that space not be worth the time it takes to reinitialise `mem_C`.

Comment: Huh? If `T` is `vector<bla>` for example, then when the constructor runs it is an empty vector  ; setting it equal to an empty vector does not free anything and just wastes time.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought you were talking about `rhs.mem_C = T();` in the move constructor.

Comment: @M.M But anyway, regarding your first comment, I don't quite understand what you are referencing with the difference between class types and non-class types in regards to this. Can you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: Not sure what sort of elaboration you are looking for. Class types invoke a move constructor when a move is requested, non-class types (e.g. pointers) don't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The move assignment/constructors for the contained types must leave the objects in an "acceptable" state, whatever that means for that type.  Nothing outside the type being moved should have any responsibility for maintaining the state of the object.

Also, you want to make sure you're calling move *constructors* of contained types in your parent move *constructor*, not the contained type's move *assignment* as you are in your example:

```
// move constructor calls move constructor of contained elements
C (C<T>&& rhs) : mem_c(std::move(rhs.mem_c))
{
    // anything in here is using already-constructed data members
}

// move assignment calls move assignment of contained elements
C & operator=(C<T>&& rhs) {
    mem_c = std::move(rhs.mem_c);
}
```